# Android dynamic layout performance

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a potentially large number of elements to display inside a scroll view.

The scroll view is inside a viewflipper, so the scroll view is only created when the user hits a button to flip the view.

I dynamically add a "row" for each entry that I need to show, and populate the row accordingly.

When I've got a large number of elements to display, the scroll view takes a long time to instantiate.

The scroll view looks like :

```
<framelayout>
...
<linear layout>
...
<viewflipper>
...

           <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_view_viewflip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="75dip" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/scroll_view_linear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

I populate the scroll view with rows that look like: (a separate XML layout)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_name"
    style="@style/SearchTableColumn"
    android:layout_weight="25" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_value"
    style="@style/SearchTableColumn"
    android:layout_weight="25" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_value"
    style="@style/SearchTableColumn"
    android:layout_weight="25" />

<NumberPicker         
    android:id="@+id/picker_value"
    style="@style/SearchTableColumn"
    android:layout_weight="25" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spin_value"
    style="@style/SearchTableColumn"
    android:layout_weight="25" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_units"
    style="@style/SearchTableColumn"
    android:layout_weight="25" />
```

And the code does, more or less:

```
LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.attribute_row, null);
// multiple row.findViewById() for the elements on the row
// set up which element will be shown or hidden and set values
layout.addView(row);
```

From doing a trace, the bulk of the time *appears* to be in the inflater/inflate() function.

Are there things I can do in the XML, or in my row-creation to improve speed ?  We're talking about maybe 100s of rows. Other questions have indicated a list view is a bad idea for performance, and my data is slightly-tree-view like (but not interested in using a 3rd party tree-view control).

I could implement an async task to fill the scroll view in the background, and add synchronization logic to "wait" when the view-flipper button is pressed, but wondering if there are better options.

Comment: I believe you'll want to add the rows into a `ListView`, as it will automatically recycle the views not visible on the page (`ScrapViews`).

Comment: I can give that a try - but wrangling my data set into an adapter might be ugly, and I don't want to lose a tree-view like display (using cheap/simple indentation to show parent/child relationship).

Comment: 100's of rows. You've got to use an adapter.